# How to use Progress Bar with my Functions? The method I used is not working well

Tags: c#, windows

How to use Progress Bar with my Functions? The method I used is not working well.

```
 var progress = new Progress<BL.ProgressReport>();
                byte[] wpdf1;
                string nnam = "1";
                File.Delete(nnam);
                FileStream fs;
                this.dataGridView1.Sort(this.dataGridView1.Columns[10], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
                button1.Enabled = false;
                List<string> list = new List<string>();
                int h;
                for (h = 0; h <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2; h++)                 
                progress = new Progress<BL.ProgressReport>();
                for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2; i++)

                {
                    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2 == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        wpdf1 = (byte[])(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value);

                    string nn = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    if (i == 0)
                        file1 = wpdf1;
                    else if (i >= 1)
                        file1 = mergePdfs(file1, wpdf1).ToArray();
                        list.Add(h.ToString());
                        lbDownload.Text = "Working...";
                        progress.ProgressChanged += (o, report) =>
                        {
                           lbDownload.Text = String.Format("Processing...{0}%", report.PercentComplete);
                            progressBar1.Value = report.PercentComplete;
                            progressBar1.Update();
                        };
                    }
                    await ProcessData(list, progress);
                }
                lbDownload.Text = "Done !";
                fs = new FileStream(nnam, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                fs.Write(file1, 0, file1.Length);
                namepdf = nnam;
                fs.Close();
                Process.Start(nnam);
```

In this method the progressBar loads more than once according to the number of iterations, so how can I make it work well by loading only once and consistent with the completion of the process

Comment: Currently, you are initializing `progress` more than once, that's probably not what you want.

Comment: This method does not work correctly. I want to use Download for this process, which is to collect the PDF files related to the dataGridView and the progressBar works correctly and well!